# Writing median rather than mean

Tags: average, means, median

I have some code to calculate the mean bias between two arrays.

$$mean_{bias}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i-b_i}{n}$$

and was hoping to represent the median instead:

$$median_{bias}=Median(a-b)$$

Does something like this hold true? But it's not sorted so index will not be the middle:

$$median_{bias}=\sum_{i=n/2}^{n/2+1}a_i-b_i$$

How can I represent this?

Thanks

Comment: This question does not concern mathematics and would be better suited for [Tex.SE] Stackexchange.

Comment: I tried there first and was suggested to ask here instead.

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: You can write median bias = median a - median b

Comment: I was hoping to express it symbolically

Comment: Are you asking for a formula for the median of the difference of two lists or for a way to write a formula in TeX?

Comment: The formula only, I can convert it into Tex myself.

Comment: You may want to edit your question and title to reflect that

Comment: Oooh you want the formula for the median of a_i-b-i ? It does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to write something like this:

\begin{gather}
bias_{\text{median}}
= \frac12\left(\max_i\left\{a_i-b_i \mid
\left\lvert\left\{j\mid a_i-b_i > a_j-b_j\right\}\right\rvert < \tfrac n2\right\} \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad 
+ \min_i\left\{a_i-b_i \mid
\left\lvert\left\{j\mid a_i-b_i < a_j-b_j\right\}\right\rvert < \tfrac n2\right\}
\right)
\end{gather}

This is a way of saying that if $n$ is odd, you take the value $a_i - b_i$ that partitions the list of values $a_j - b_j$ 
(excluding $a_i - b_i$ itself) into two equal sets, one of values less than 
$a_i - b_i$ and one of values greater; and if $n$ is even you take the mean
of the *two* values $a_i - b_i$ and $a_{i'} - b_{i'}$ that partition the list
of values $a_j - b_j$ (excluding those two values) into two equal sets.

But I think this is a rather horrible expression.

A better way is probably to define some notation of your own, for example,

> The notation $\text{median}(S)$ represents the median of the set $S$,

followed at some later time by an expression such as

$$ \text{median} \{a_i - b_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}. $$

Comment: So there isn't a nice way of doing it. Interesting. I agree that the first one does the job, but it's a bit much!  I think I will just define that median means median like your suggestion 2. Thanks very much!